# Using variables in plink

Tags: linux, plink

I am using plink in a batch file. The content of this batch file is like this:

```
plink -ssh user@APP_FE -pw passwd -m Prepare.txt > result\prepare\Prepare.trc
```

In the Prepare.txt file I want to use some variables. How should I implement this?